# How to forecast ad impressions to avoid oversell?

Tags: ads

Assuming that my website viewers have several tags. Advertisers can buy some targeted impressions within a specific period time. Then how can I forecast ad impressions in the near future to avoid oversell? How to estimate remaining ad impressions inventory after an advertiser give an order on targeted impressions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Ad Manager as an ad server, 
forecasting is available in both Small Business (free version) and Premium.
It allows to view [traffic forecast](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7359543?hl=en) and check traffic availability for a [specific line item](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/82234?hl=en). From my experience, the accuracy of such a forecast is acceptable.

If you're using something else it's hard to answer your question because the details are missing in the question.

If you don't use an ad server and place your banners manually, it's just a matter of using excel-like spreadsheets and doing the math *manually*:

- predicting the amount of inventory you'll have (based on Google Analytics)
- manually slicing it between advertisers and checking whether you've got enough inventory
- coding banners placements on your pages so that your traffic is split correctly between advertisers